# Not getting expected output - Cheerio

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape naukri.com website for getting jobs out of it using cheerio. Expected Output is text of the whole page instead of which I am getting the following output.

```
<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NX744H"height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>     
<img src="https://www.naukri.com/akam/11/pixel_74f1c4ec?a=dD1hYjJmYTA0N2JkNDM1ODI5NmY0YmZlNzk1ZTMxNGI4YTU1YmEyNWI4JmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" />
```

**Here is the code**

```
'use strict';
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function jobUrls() {
    try {
        const siteUrl = 'https://www.naukri.com/cse-jobs?k=cse';
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: siteUrl,
        });
        const $ = cheerio.load(data);
        console.log($.text())
    }
    catch (er) {
        console.log(er)
    }
}
jobUrls();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website `https://www.naukri.com/cse-jobs?k=cse` is most likely SPA (single page application). It can't be scraped in straightforward way. This is the difference of accessing the site using browser and axios.

- (axios) : request HTML --> get HTML response containing scripts --> done
- (browser) : request HTML --> get HTML response containing scripts --> run scripts --> get more data --> render --> done.

This is the limitation of `axios`, it does only one HTTP request. If you need to scrape the entire page, consider using headless browser in Node. [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) is a well-known package.